# Is there any way to avoid encoding error when using ActionMailer with Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, actionmailer

I keep getting the following error when sending a simple e-mail via ActionMailer in Rails:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `encode!' for "Hello":String
```

This is triggered whenever the following is run:

```
def hello_world_email()

   mail( :from => "me",
      :to => "you,
      :subject => "Hello World"
       )
end
```

From researching this, it looks like it's caused by the differences between Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.*, which has built-in character encoding support.

Is there any way of getting ActionMailer to work with Ruby 1.8.7 and avoid this issue? (I can upgrade Ruby on my machine, but I can't do the same for everyone else working on the project). Given that the whole of Rails 3.0.9 (of which ActionMailer is a part) is meant to work with Ruby 1.8.7, I keep thinking that there must be a way...

Note: My exact version of Ruby is `ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]` (pre-installed on OSX).

Answer (score 1):

You may have an issue with using Ruby 1.8 and having a constant Encoding defined by a gem.
For example we found an issue with a class that was including REXML at a global scope.

The line in question in the library was:

```
value.encode!(charset) if defined?(Encoding) && charset
```

This is checking for a global constant called Encoding. (Which could be defined in any gem at global scope.) Our problem was actually the include which then made REXML::Encoding available everywhere as Encoding. You could try grepping or acking your codebase for "module Encoding" or "class Encoding".

Hope this helps.

The stack trace below defines the problem.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `encode!' for "Generate":String
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:169:in `encode'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:138:in `fold'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:108:in `wrapped_value'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:70:in `do_encode'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb:52:in `encoded'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/field.rb:123:in `send'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/field.rb:123:in `method_missing'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/header.rb:190:in `encoded'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/header.rb:189:in `each'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/header.rb:189:in `encoded'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/message.rb:1708:in `encoded'
actionmailer (3.0.10) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:445:in `set_payload_for_mail'
actionmailer (3.0.10) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:425:in `deliver_mail'
activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionmailer (3.0.10) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:424:in `deliver_mail'
mail (2.2.19) lib/mail/message.rb:230:in `deliver'
```

Comment: Thanks. Will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, when trying to test my devise confirmation emails. Weird thing was, running the test isolated did not throw this exception. Running the whole stack did. After doing a binary search, i found, that one of my specs used REXML to parse some content.

```
    require 'spec_helper'
    require 'rexml/document'
    include REXML
    doc = Document.new(response.body)
```

I dont't know, why i included REXML, presumably, because i wanted to save the REXML:: in front of Document. But changing the code to this fixed the problem:

```
    require 'spec_helper'
    require 'rexml/document'
    doc = REXML::Document.new(response.body)
```

if you happen to use code like this somewhere, this may fix this encode! issue with ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue to be with the mailer gem, changing to 2.2.13 fixed it for me.

Comment: I couldn't manage to do this, as "rails (= 3.0.9) depends on mail (~> 2.2.19)"